# Read from File in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I would simply like to read from a text file in Objective C.

Here's my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Pie" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"%@",content);
    [pool drain];
    return 0; }
```

The ouput reads: **2011-12-23 15:49:12.649 FileReader[1309:707] (null)**

I am using XCode 4.1.  I included "Pie.txt" using **File >> Add File to ...**.  I also (not sure if this is necessary) added the file using **Build Phases >> Copy Files**.

Thanks.  I've been trying to do this all day with no luck.  I am pretty close to scraping my face off.  This should be a pretty simple task.  Please save the skin on my face from total destruction by answering this question.

Comment: What does your file actually contain? Is it actually text? Data? Also, how is the text file formatted?

Comment: The error object will give a better clue. Do this: before the `NSString *content ...` line, declare a NSError by adding `NSError *error = nil;` . Then, instead of passing `NULL` to `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error`, pass `&error` in its place. Finally, add a `NSLog(@"%@", error);` at the end and post the resulting message.

Comment: After you've followed sidyll's excellent advice, you might want to look inside your app's bundle to make sure that your file is being copied properly.

Answer (score 1):

The path calculated by `NSBundle` isn't matching the actual location of the file at runtime. To fix this, go to the **Copy Files** build phase and change the Destination to **Products Directory**. Also, uncheck the **Copy only when installing** checkbox. You might need to build clean after making these changes. When you build and run, your code should work.